# CreateJS Flash CC MovieClip(root) is there a way to do this with JavaScript and Flash CC

Tags: html, flash, html5-canvas, createjs

I have been recently building a project in Flash CC using the CreateJS Library for HTML Canvas.

In ActionScript 3 you could use MovieClip(root) to call functions and access variables from within an instance of a symbol's timeline to the main timeline. Does anyone know if there is there a similar way to do this using CreateJS and Flash CC for the canvas?

Answer (score 5):

Instances in an EaselJS display list can access their Stage via `getStage()`. However, in Flash's output the authoring "root" is actually a child on the EaselJS Stage. You can see this in the generated HTML where it instantiates "exportRoot" and adds it to the stage. So assuming you haven't added anything else to the stage, your "root" will be its first child.

For example, assuming you have defined a function like this on your root timeline:

`this.doSomething = function() { /* etc */ }`

You can call it from a symbol's timeline like so:

`this.getStage().getChildAt(0).doSomething();`

If you want to play really quick and dirty, you could also access the global `exportRoot` variable defined in the HTML directly, by putting something like this in your Symbol's timeline:

`exportRoot.doSomething();`

Its worth noting though, that just like in ActionScript, referencing up to root is *usually* an indication that your architecture could use some rethinking.

Comment: Wow Grant Skinner thanks for taking the time to reply. I solved the issue I was having by restructuring my design but it took a little more time to test it what I was trying to do.

Comment: Your examples work if the code calling the function on the main timeline is in the first frame of the of the symbol's timeline but it doesn't work if I put it on a different frame which is what I was trying to do. Just was wondering if this is something that was possible using createJS with Flash?

Comment: I just tested using the code from above. Method declaration on frame 1 of the root timeline, and `this.getStage().getChildAt(0).doSomething();` on frame 5 (of 10) of a child symbol instance. It worked fine. Maybe you're doing something odd?

Comment: I shut down flash and tested it again just now and it is working properly in the file now. I think working with flash in and out of sleep mode might have been the problem. Thank you so much for your help. I have so many other questions too.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the exported html file. It will include a 'stage' variable. If you're symbol has an instancename of `mysymbol` than you can access it via `stage.mysymbol`or `stage["mysymbol"]`.

Comment: stage is the same as root in this case

Comment: Thanks for the response. I see what you are talking about in the html file. So to call function on the main timeline within a frame on another symbol's timeline I would call stage.functionName(); to call the particular function?  I just tried that and it didn't work. Got an undefined error.